# Checking if two lines are crossing

Tags: graphics, lua, love2d, graph

How can I check if two lines (created with function `love.graphics.line`) are crossing themselves? I may use this ability to create procedural maps via graphs.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about game development within the scope defined in the help center. See http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63295/how-to-determine-the-point-of-intersection-of-two-lines

Comment: @MrCranky I think this is not directly game dev related. But line intersection is a common geometry problem. To some extent we accept graphics, geometry, math and physics questions. http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/should-we-better-define-the-scope-of-gdse-to-include-graphics-programming-and-im

Comment: I was going on the basis that we closed an almost identical line-intersection problem (the one I linked to) as off-topic, including a comment suggesting it was better served on math.stackexchange. Even if it's on topic, it's most certainly a duplicate.

Comment: I agree it's a duplicate.

Comment: This page lists code snippets for Love2D on general math functions such as finding the point of intersection between two lines: http://love2d.org/wiki/General_math